# Swift - Certificate request with Proof of Possession

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, certificate, pkcs#10

I have build a PKCS#10 Certificate request with proof of possession element that will be sent towards Certification Authority via ACS to obtain the User certificate. In Android app it is used the SpongyCastle package ([SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/blob/spongy-master/core/src/main/java/org/spongycastle/asn1/crmf/ProofOfPossession.java))

Has anyone any idea how to do that in swift?

Thanks

Comment: using OpenSSL, maybe?

Comment: @holex can you explain how it works? Tried get informed but didn't understand how i can implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution!

Just used that library (https://github.com/cbaker6/CertificateSigningRequestSwift) and changed the function "buldCertificationRequestInfo" in order to have the certificate as was wanted.